# Android Grid View positioning

Tags: android, view, grid

In my application there is a grid view which contains letters from A to Z,when ever i'm installing my application in some Big size screen mobiles grid view position is flowing according to the screen sizes. I'm facing this problem with big screen mobiles and small screen mobiles,when compared to average screens the position is very good,what i need is which attributes should be written for the grid view to match all the screen sizes without flowing or scrolling Thanks in advance

```
 <GridView
 android:id="@+id/letters"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:layout_marginTop="250sp"
 android:horizontalSpacing="5sp"
 android:numColumns="9"
 android:padding="5sp"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
 android:verticalSpacing="5sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid view parameters should be
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: i have tried as fill parent but its not aligning properly i need it as a keyboard which should be at the bottom of the screen matching the layout of the mobile screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't know did i clearly understand your problem but if you want to make a grid view fits all screen sizes without scrolling you have to set your grid view rows' height dynamically.

Setting views' height dynamically is a bit hard operation too. Because when you inflate layout, views' height is measuring in a thread. Here's a sample i use for this operation.

```
final LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout)mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.ll_categories);
        wrapper.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // hide view here so that its height has been already computed
                Constants.rowHeight2 = wrapper.getMeasuredHeight() / Constants.VISIBLE_ITEM_COUNT;
                initActivity();
            }
        });
```

Or you can override onmeasure to get final height of your grid view. Later you can divide your list size and find each row's height.

I hope my answer will help you.